# How to return a list of objects along with Exception

Tags: java

My Java program has a method that returns a List. It populates the list using various SQL queries. In some cases, the data may be absent. In that case I've to throw an Exception. Since it is a list, list may contain valid data. Is it possible to get the list as well as catch the Exceptions?

```
public List<Student> getStudentInfo(){
    //Contains some static info like name, dob of a Student
    List<Student> students = getStudentStaticInfo();
    try{
        for (Student student: students){
            student.setTotalMarks(getStudentMark(student.getId()));
            ...
        }
    catch(FailedToFetchDataException e) {
        throw new Exception("Failed to fetch data");
    } finally {
        return students;
    }

}
```

In this case, the method returns the list of valid student information. But in case of an Exception, I'm not able to find out.

Is there a way to handle both, get the valid info as well as get the exceptional scenarios.

Comment: Obviously the list is empty when you are getting the exception then how come you are expecting the result of the list?

Comment: You should create an object which contains the data and a list of error messages.

Comment: You could create a custom exception that includes the list. That being said, this seems like a very odd requirement. You should probably rethink your logic to allow the method to either return a value or throw an exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method will stop as soon as the Exception is thrown, if not it will have to handle multiple exceptions. You can do this.

```
public List<Student> getStudentInfo(
                     BiConsumer<FailedToFetchDataException, Student> handleError) {
    //Contains some static info like name, dob of a Student
    List<Student> students = getStudentStaticInfo();
    for (Student student: students) {
        try{
            student.setTotalMarks(getStudentMark(student.getId()));
            ...
        } catch(FailedToFetchDataException e) {
            handleError.accept(e, student);
        }
    }
    return students;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could let the caller pass in a List object:

```
public void getStudentInfo(List<Student> list){
    ...
}
```

Inside the method you populate the list with your result, and at the end throw the Exception if an error occurred.

Therefore the caller gets notified of the error and still has the valid data returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom exception that `overrides` `FailedToFetchDataException` and attach private fields, like `Student` and `List<Student>`

You can do something like this:

```
CustomException e = new CustomException(msg);
e.setStudents(list);
throw e;
```

Comment: No. please don't do this. very bad practice

Comment: Could you explain why this is a bad practice?

Comment: Exception are used for exceptions. not for returning values. don't do something just because it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to create your own exception like:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {

   private List<Student> list;

   public myException(List<Student> list) {
      this.list = list;
   }

   public List<Student> getList() {
      return list;
   }

   public void setList(List<Student> list) {
      this.list = list;
   }

}
```

An the throw this instead of `Exception` when you catch `FailedToFetchDataException`

However, It would probably be better to just return the list when you catch the `FailedToFetchDataException`

Answer (score 0):

If you can still use data in an exception scenario then you could pass in a list to the method, that you insert data into. For example:

```
public List<Student> getStudentInfo(List<Student> studentResults){
//Contains some static info like name, dob of a Student
List<Student> students = getStudentStaticInfo();
try{
    for (Student student: students){
        student.setTotalMarks(getStudentMark(student.getId()));
        studentResults.add(student);
        ...
    }
catch(FailedToFetchDataException e) {
    throw new Exception("Failed to fetch data");
} finally {
    return students;
}
}
```

Now `studentResults` will be populated with either:

- All the student records if no exception occurred
- The student records that were processed *before* the exception occurred.

If you'd like all the student records regardless of whether `setTotalMarks` threw an exception or not, you could alternatively call `getStudentStaticInfo` at your call site.